# How to animate moving ball

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am attempting to do a very simple animation and move a ball from one position to another. I have attempted to create a ball class and method to move the ball given a velocity, position and time.
However, the output does not update the ball position as predicted but stays in the same position.
The code can be seen below:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
pl.matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

class ball:
    def __init__(self,pos,vel,r=1,m=1):
        self._pos = np.array(pos,dtype="float64")
        self._vel = np.array(vel,dtype="float64")
        self._r = r
        self._mass = m
        self._patch=pl.Circle((self._pos),self._r, fc='red',ec='black') 

    def move(self,dt):
        newpos = self._pos + self._vel*dt
        self._pos = newpos
        self._patch = pl.Circle((self._pos),self._r,fc='red',ec='black')
        return self

k=ball([0,0],[7,9])
f=pl.figure()
ax = pl.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10),aspect='1')
ax.add_patch(k._patch)
print(k._patch)
pl.pause(5)
k.move(1)
pl.pause(5)
pl.show()
```

I have tried figuring out what is wrong but self._patch is updating it's position and if I ax.add_patch the new patch then it appears - however, there are then two balls on the plot. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran the code I noticed that the patch wasn't updating on the plot but the position of the ball was changing as expected - to get around this I added 2 lines to the `move(self, dt)` function. The first removes the old patch, and the second adds the new patch with the updated position.

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
pl.matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

class ball:
    def __init__(self,pos,vel,r=1,m=1):
        self._pos = np.array(pos,dtype="float64")
        self._vel = np.array(vel,dtype="float64")
        self._r = r
        self._mass = m
        self._patch=pl.Circle((self._pos),self._r, fc='red',ec='black') 

    def move(self,dt):
        newpos = self._pos + self._vel*dt
        self._pos = newpos
        self._patch.remove()
        self._patch = pl.Circle((self._pos),self._r,fc='red',ec='black')
        ax.add_patch(self._patch)
        return self

k=ball([0,0],[7,9])
f=pl.figure()
ax = pl.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10),aspect='1')
ax.add_patch(k._patch)

print(k._patch)
pl.pause(5)
k.move(1)
pl.pause(5)

pl.show()
```